# How to configure a filebeat daemon set to handle multiple logging templates

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, openshift, redhat, devops

We have an app that is deployed on openshift and we use filebeat as a daemonset to collect the container logs and send them to elastic-search. The problem is that we have different logging templates. So I was wondering if there is a way to configure multiple filebeat configurations for the same daemonset deployment instead of deploying a daemonset for every logging template.

Answer (score 0):

I think it need to create each `daemonset` for each template.
But you can control where the `daemonset` should run using [nodeSelector](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/admin_guide/scheduling/node_selector.html#admin-guide-sched-selector-config).

For example, you have 2 templates and each template should apply different nodes.
Then you would create 2 daemonset configured as different node labels and logging templates.

```
node1 log=template1 ---> daemonset1 with "nodeSelector: log=template1"
node2 log=template1 ---> daemonset1 with "nodeSelector: log=template1"
node3 log=template2 ---> daemonset2 with "nodeSelector: log=template2"
```

I hope it help you.